# How to get iframe src particular content value in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an iframe for a cross-domain site. I try to get gold and silver price to my window from this iframe src but i cn't get this value. Please any one give solution for this.. and this is iframe src link--->

```
1.<iframe id="val1" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" height="87" width="196" allowtransparency="true" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" src="http://comrates.investing.com/index.php?force_lang=1&pairs_ids=8830;8836;&header-text-color=%23FFFFFF&curr-name-color=%230059b0&inner-text-color=%23000000&green-text-color=%232A8215&green-background=%23B7F4C2&red-text-color=%23DC0001&red-background=%23FFE2E2&inner-border-color=%23CBCBCB&border-color=%23cbcbcb&bg1=%23F6F6F6&bg2=%23ffffff&open=hide&month=hide&high=hide&low=hide&change=hide&change_in_percents=hide&last_update=hide"></iframe>
2.<iframe id="val2" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" height="68" width="151" allowtransparency="true" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" src="http://fxrates.investing.com/index.php?force_lang=1&pairs_ids=160;&header-text-color=%23FFFFFF&curr-name-color=%230059b0&inner-text-color=%23000000&green-text-color=%232A8215&green-background=%23B7F4C2&red-text-color=%23DC0001&red-background=%23FFE2E2&inner-border-color=%23CBCBCB&border-color=%23cbcbcb&bg1=%23F6F6F6&bg2=%23ffffff&bid=hide&ask=show&last=hide&open=hide&high=hide&low=hide&change=hide&change_in_percents=hide&last_update=hide"></iframe>
```

Comment: if the sites are not from the same domain as the page your javascript lives in you cant, cross-domain policy will not allow it

Answer (score 0):

i would do by using  server  side first and the retrieving the value from your own domain